# Different output of df-h on Solaris 10 server for swap memory

Tags: solaris

I am getting different output of df -h for swap memory (/tmp filesystem) on Solaris 10 server at different times. I could not find much on the actual reason, and also I am confused how can it be so?

I am getting these outputs at different times.

1) ***w0110Da04*** ins /apps/ins> df -h

```
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0      9.9G   1.5G   8.3G    16%    /
/devices                 0K     0K     0K     0%    /devices
ctfs                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/contract
proc                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /proc
mnttab                   0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                   508M   1.0M   507M     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                    0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/object
sharefs                  0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s3       20G   4.2G    15G    22%    /usr
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap2.so.1
                        20G   4.2G    15G    22%    /lib/libc.so.1
fd                       0K     0K     0K     0%    /dev/fd
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s4       20G   7.3G    12G    38%    /var
***swap                   578M    71M   507M    13%    /tmp***
swap                   507M    32K   507M     1%    /var/run
/dev/dsk/c1t1d0s0      135G   101G    33G    76%    /int01
/dev/dsk/c1t2d0s0      135G   6.9G   126G     6%    /int02
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s5       20G   637M    19G     4%    /apps
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s6       15G   7.4G   7.2G    51%    /export/home
LDAP                   244G    57G   187G    24%    /LDAP

Here, /tmp has total size 578 MB. But in the second output below, I have:

2) root@***w0110Da04*** # df -h
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0      9.9G   1.5G   8.3G    16%    /
/devices                 0K     0K     0K     0%    /devices
ctfs                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/contract
proc                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /proc
mnttab                   0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                    28G   1.0M    28G     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                    0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/object
sharefs                  0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s3       20G   4.2G    15G    22%    /usr
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap2.so.1
                        20G   4.2G    15G    22%    /lib/libc.so.1
fd                       0K     0K     0K     0%    /dev/fd
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s4       20G   7.3G    12G    38%    /var
***swap                    29G   707M    28G     3%    /tmp***
swap                    28G    36K    28G     1%    /var/run
/dev/dsk/c1t1d0s0      135G   103G    30G    78%    /int01
/dev/dsk/c1t2d0s0      135G   6.9G   126G     6%    /int02
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s5       20G   637M    19G     4%    /apps
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s6       15G   7.4G   7.2G    51%    /export/home
LDAP                   244G    56G   188G    23%    /LDAP
```

Here, /tmp has 29GB as total size.

Both are swap memories, So how is there so much size difference for the same server but at different times and that too for total swap size?

Please help.

Comment: Can you show the output of `swap -l` ? Plausible explanation is that the first df was run before one or more swap areas were enabled.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:openldap]?

Comment: @EJP:
Actually, I am running openldap on this machine. And the temporary directory field in DB_CONFIG file is pointing to /tmp.

Comment: Basically, I am using it as directory structure on my machine and whenever any queries are run, they are operated on openldap directory structure. Also, I have similar LDAP configurations of the same LDAP release(2.3.43) on another machine also, but there I am not getting any such problem. And due to this problem, at some point of time (after approx 5 days), no more swap is available.

Comment: @Mark: 
Actually, the output of df in which swap memory is 578M occurs after 5 days . Initially, when I restart my LDAP binary (slapd), the swap size is 29GB. But, after somedays, the size reduces to 578M. If I again restart my slapd binary, then again the whole swap is available and no swap space issue occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Mby your openldap or some app use tmp dir ? Try ls -laerth /tmp